# Why app_dev.php is available in production?

Tags: symfony

I have production website and notice that can be also accessed using app_dev.php in the url with debug toolbar. Under apache vhost I have:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

How to disable app_dev.php on production?

Comment: Remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and restrict it to a smaller area (static file directories).

Comment: Are you using a modified `app_dev.php` file ? becasue, the original one has a check to prevent that.

Comment: @Himal yes you're right copied original file solved to problem

Comment: Technically, you don't need that file on the production server at all. if you aren't going to access the `dev` environment on the production server then just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you shoudn't have app_dev.php in production, it should be removed when you build the project.

Or what you could do instead of removing it, is to use environment variable to defined what is the SYMFONY_ENV and to use in the app_dev.php, if it's not dev, then you should denied or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

`app_dev.php` is available beacuse:

1. File exists
2. Access to the file is allowed.

What you should do is either to remove the file or forbid access to it from .htaccess

Also, on `app_dev.php` there should be a line only allowing access from certain IP addresses (althought previous solutions are more robust).